# How can I map a Result object of 2 records (many to one) into their respective record objects in jOOQ?

Tags: java, join, jooq

I have a table `X` and another one `Y`. I want to load a record from `X` which has a foreign key to `Y` so I perform a left join:

```
X x = dslContext.select()
                .from(Tables.X)
                .leftJoin(Tables.Y)
                .on(Tables.X.SOME_ID.eq(Tables.Y.ID))
                .where(Tables.X.IS.eq(id))
                .fetchOptionalInto(XRecord.class)
```

this is perfectly fine but i'm a bit puzzled about how I extract `Y` from this? I tried using `into`, but the problem is that if there are columns in `Y` which are also present in `X` I will see the values from `X` not `Y` when I try to map the result `into` an `YRecord`. I know that there is `fetchGroups` but I only have an `XRecord` to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your records from a generic record type as follows:

```
Record r = dslContext
                .select()
                .from(Tables.X)
                .leftJoin(Tables.Y)
                .on(Tables.X.SOME_ID.eq(Tables.Y.ID))
                .where(Tables.X.IS.eq(id))
                .fetchOne();

if (r != null) {
    XRecord x = r.into(Tables.X);
    YRecord y = r.into(Tables.Y);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try this!

Comment: What can I do if I have multiple results for `Tables.Y`? Can I fetch them into a list?

Comment: The jOOQ way would be to use `ResultQuery.fetchGroups()` to produce a `Map<XRecord, List<YRecord>>`. Or you could use a third party tool like simple flat mapper: https://simpleflatmapper.org/0106-getting-started-jooq.html

Comment: Thanks, these worked! So the best practice for many to one is above, and for one to many is the `fetchGroups`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. The jOOQ code generator creates an object named `Keys` which contains all the keys in your project. With that you can use

```
xRecord.fetchParent(X_TO_Y_ID_FKEY)
```

and it will fetch the parent (also works with children) for you.
There is one caveat though. The `Record` needs to be `attach`ed to a `DSLContext` to be able to use it this way.

Comment: I recommend you don't do this as a workaround for what you're trying to achieve here! This produces an N+1 problem. Better use the join output instead.

Comment: What is a use case for `fetchParent` then?

Comment: Occasionally, you want to lazily fetch a parent record for a given child record. But in this case, for N child records, it's better to fetch the N parent records eagerly using a join.